# SSRS 2008 R2 - How do you show data points in the legend for a column chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I was wondering if it is possible to show all the data points in the legend? I have tried everything I could think of.  Editing the custom legend text in the series properties did not do anything for me, unless I am overlooking something. See the image below to have an idea of what I am going for.  Please let me know if this is even possible in SSRS 2008 R2 (Note: This is a report generated from some other tool that I am trying to emulate as close as possible.  Think it may have been Excel actually)  Thank you!

[image: Column Chart]

Edit:  Here is what I have currently:

[image: Column Chart]

I am just trying to get the legend of my chart to look like the chart above.

Comment: What "data points" are missing?

Comment: See my edit up above.  I want to show the data label values that are currently being show on the chart itself down below in my legend as shown in the first screen shot.